# Does a Jenkins Master need Perforce installed

Tags: build, jenkins, continuous-integration, perforce

We have a Jenkins master/slave configuration and Perforce is installed on all masters. We just had an unrelated incident occur that made us renew our .p4tickets on all masters and slaves and we came to find that perforce had been removed by someone on our team about a week ago without telling anyone.

Our jobs are setup to wipe completely new the workspaces on the slaves every time a build occurs so that we can issue a p4 sync every time. We build several times a day. Perforce is installed both on the masters and the slaves.

The problem is that the master that had Perforce missing has been doing builds successfully for a week now.

I have been operating under the thought that with the architecture we have, Perforce is doing a push from the Master to the Slave since the jobs are kept on the Master. Is this incorrect?

Regards,
-Caolan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the Perforce client on the Jenkins master unless it's set up to run builds that need to pull code from Perforce.  If all your builds run on slaves, you don't need Perforce on the master.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the new [p4 plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/P4+Plugin) you don't need to install any `p4` clients on the Master or the Slave.  The p4 plugin uses a native p4java API to talk directly to the Perforce Server.